# Using unmanaged library

Tags: c++, unmanaged, managed

So in visual studio i have my solution with two projects, first one is managed c++ code and second one is unmanaged c++ library ([waffles](http://waffles.sourceforge.net/)). I want to use classes from library in my managed code.

If i simply add 'include "GMacros.h"', then i get 'cannot compile with /clr' error. Tried to wrap include in #pragma unmanaged/managed, but it doesnt seem to work.

Is there anything i can do without editing external library code or writing any wrappers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmanaged code can't be called directly in managed .NET. You need to add `__declspec(dllexport)` to your functions' declarations that should be visible outside the unmanaged library:

```
public:
    void __declspec(dllexport) MyUnmanagedMethod();
```

And then in your managed code write a simple wrapper like this:

```
public ref class Wrapper
{
public:
    [DllImport("MyUnmanagedLibrary.dll")]
    static extern void MyUnmanagedMethod();
}
```

Now you can call `Wrapper.MyUnmanagedMethod` like any other static method from you managed code.

Comment: What if i dont have the .dll file? Only bunch of .h and .cpp

Comment: .dll file is created by the compiler when you build your unmanaged project. Look for it in  your Debug or Release directory

Answer (score 1):

The generic solution is to wrap the library calls in thin wrapper functions/classes whose header files you can include in managed code. Not very pretty but will get you there.

Answer (score 0):

P/Invoke with the DLLImport attribute also requires you to get down and dirty with marshalling the function parameters, if it has any, to CLR types. So for example a `DWORD` becomes an `int`, `IN HANDLE` can become an `IntPtr`, `LPDWORD` becomes an `out int`, `LPVOID` can usually be marshalled as a `byte[]`... and so on. See a decent summary about it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/essentialpinvoke.aspx).

An example pulled out of my recent project where I had to interface with a DLL for an old digital output box:

```
//This function's header in the DLL was:
//BOOL _stdcall fnPerformaxComSendRecv(IN HANDLE pHandle, IN LPVOID wBuffer, IN DWORD dwNumBytesToWrite, IN DWORD dwNumBytesToRead, OUT LPVOID rBuffer);
[DllImport("PerformaxCom.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool fnPerformaxComSendRecv(IntPtr pHandle, byte[] wBuffer, int dwNumBytesToWrite, int dwNumBytesToRead, byte[] rBuffer);
```

Comment: How do you pass complex type objects to a P/Invoke method?